# How to run a certain function when the page is visited with a specific URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function, dom

I am building a page in which the content shown changes with category buttons. I want to link the homepage to this page using multiple URLs so that user can jump into the category they wish before visiting the page. This question is probably pretty basic and I have seen some explenations; however, I am pretty new to web-dev so I'd appreciate if anybody could help and provide detailed explanation :prayer-hands:

My code if you need it. When user clicks on any "See More" on homepage, they will be directed to the same page but with different categories open.

```
function renderArticleSections() {

    const titles = ["Electrical", "Mechanical", "Computer", "Chemical", "Biomedical"]
    const categoryLinks = ["#a","#b", "#c", "#d", "#e"]

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        const section = document.createElement("section")
        section.setAttribute("class", "articles-section")
        const categoryWrapper = document.createElement("div")
        categoryWrapper.setAttribute("class", "articles-category-wrapper")
        const category = document.createElement("p")
        category.setAttribute("class", "articles-category")
        category.textContent = titles[i]
        // <hr>
        const categoryLink = document.createElement("a")
        categoryLink.setAttribute("href", categoryLinks[i])
        categoryLink.setAttribute("class", "category-link")
        categoryLink.textContent = "See All"

        categoryWrapper.append(category)
        category.after(document.createElement("hr"), categoryLink)

        section.append(categoryWrapper)
        categoryWrapper.after(createFiveArticlesWrapper(articlesData[i]))

        document.getElementById("classroom-title").before(section)

    }
}
```

Comment: from link: `yourpage.html#section1` - to element with that ID: `<div id="section1">...</div>` - on same page: from link:  `<a href="#section1">` - to element with that ID: `<div id="section1">...</div>`

Comment: @mplungjan what you are suggesting is a different scroll locations in a page. I want different functions to execute when the user visits the page from different URLs because I want to render different contents to the page

Comment: you can still interrogate the location.hash for the intended target